# Exclude a certian field or make it Null inside a AQL query

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have problem. I have a collection `orders`. I want to get all documents and all field except the field `dataOriginSystem` inside `metaData`.
Is there an option to exclude this value, or make it null?

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(ColumnNameX, [ColumnNameY, ...])
FROM TableA
```

This my collection `orders`:

```py
[
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
},
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 'contactEditor': {'name': 'Max Power2',
  'phone': '1234567',
  'email': 'max@power.com'},
 'contactSoldToParty': {'name': 'Max Not',
  'phone': '123456789',
  'email': 'maxnot@power.com'},
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': 'Goods',
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 'orderDate': '2021-02-22',
 'orderDateBuyer': '2021-02-22',
 },
]
```

AQL

```
FOR doc IN orders RETURN doc
```

I want something like

```
FOR doc IN orders RETURN doc WITHOUT metaData_dataOriginSystem
FOR doc IN orders RETURN doc AND metaData_dataOriginSystem = NULL
```

So that the returned documents do not have the field `metaData_dataOriginSystem` or the field should be `Null`

What I want (the other fields should all exist!)

```py
[
{'_id': 'orders/213123',
 ...
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {<Removed>,
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 ...
},
OR
{'_id': 'orders/12323',
 ...
 'isCompleteDelivery': False,
 'metaData': {'dataOriginSystem': Null,
  'dataOriginWasCreatedTime': '10:12:12',},
 ...
 },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`UNSET()`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#unset) or [`UNSET_RECURSIVE()`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#unset_recursive).

```
UNSET(document, attributeName1, attributeName2, ... attributeNameN) → doc
```

Remove the attributes `attributeName1` to `attributeNameN` from document. All other attributes will be preserved.

```
FOR doc IN orders RETURN UNSET( doc, "orderData", "dataOriginSystem")
```

---

If you want to remove a nested value, you need to [`Merge`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.9/aql/functions-document.html#merge)

```
FOR doc IN orders RETURN MERGE(doc, {metaData: UNSET(doc.metaData, "dataOriginSystem")})
```